# Add numbers RegExp in big text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a big text like

```
Word 3 : 3 Word
bla-bla
....
Word (10%) 2 : 4 (15%) wORD
BLA-BLA
Word 4 : 1 Word
bla-bla
....
...
```

And I need to put `(10%)` between `Word 4` and `1 Word` like 
`Word (10%) 2 : 4 (15%) wORD` this. So the final look must be

```
Word (10%) 3 : 3 (10%) wORD
bla-bla
Word (10%) 2 : 4 (15%) wORD
bla-bla
Word  (10%) 4 : 1 (10%) Word
vla-bla
..
..
..
```

I try `/(.*?)\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*\(\d+%\)\s*(.*)\s/gm` 
[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/pO9eL5/2) but it's only find `Word  (10%) 4 : 1 (10%) Word` such patterns.

Someone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex

```
/^(\w+) +(\d+ : \d+) +(\w+)/gm
```

will match

- `(\w+)` One or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), captured by the first group and referenced by `$1`
- `[ ]+` One or more spaces
- `(\d+ : \d+)` A number, a literal `" : "` and another number, captured by the second group and referenced by `$2`
- `[ ]+` One or more spaces
- `(\w+)` One or more word characters, captured by the third group and referenced by `$3`

**Code**

```js
var regex = /^(\w+) +(\d+ : \d+) +(\w+)/gm;
var replacement = "$1 (10%) $2 (10%) $3";
var text = `Word 3 : 3 Word
bla-bla
....
Word (10%) 2 : 4 (15%) wORD
BLA-BLA
Word 4 : 1 Word
bla-bla
....
...`;
var result = text.replace( regex, replacement);

document.write("<pre>" + result + "</pre>");
```